# flake8.exceptions.FailedToLoadPlugin: Flake8 failed to load plugin "D" due to invalid syntax upon install

Tags: python, flake8

I installed flake8 and flake8 docstrings globally using this:

```
sudo pip install flake8 flake8-docstrings
```

I tried to launch flake8 but i am faced with this error:

```
flake8 --version                      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/flake8", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flake8/main/cli.py", line 18, in main
    app.run(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 393, in run
    self._run(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 380, in _run
    self.initialize(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 363, in initialize
    self.find_plugins()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 199, in find_plugins
    self.check_plugins.load_plugins()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flake8/plugins/manager.py", line 410, in load_plugins
    plugins = list(self.manager.map(load_plugin))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flake8/plugins/manager.py", line 297, in map
    yield func(self.plugins[name], *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flake8/plugins/manager.py", line 408, in load_plugin
    return plugin.load_plugin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flake8/plugins/manager.py", line 165, in load_plugin
    raise failed_to_load
flake8.exceptions.FailedToLoadPlugin: Flake8 failed to load plugin "D" due to invalid syntax (checker.py, line 668).
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by downgrading pydocstyle to `3.0.0`.

```
pip install pydocstyle=3.0.0
```